# Finding the PHP File (at run time) where a Class was Defined

Tags: php, reflection, class

Is there any reflection/introspection/magic in PHP that will let you find the PHP file where a particular class (or function) was defined?

In other words, I have the name of a PHP class, or an instantiated object.  I want to pass this to **something** (function, Reflection class, etc.) that would return the file system path where the class was defined.

```
/path/to/class/definition.php
```

I realize I could use (`get_included_files())` to get a list of all the files that have been included so far and then parse them all manually, but that's a lot of file system access for a single attempt.

I also realize I could write some additional code in our __autoload mechanism that caches this information somewhere.  However, modifying the existing __autoload is off limits in the situation I have in mind.

Hearing about extensions that can do this would be interesting, but I'd ultimately like something that can run on a "stock" install.

Comment: Magento brought me here :-]

Answer (score 268, accepted):

Try `ReflectionClass`

- [ReflectionClass::getFileName](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getfilename.php)  — Gets a filename

Example:

```
class Foo {}
$reflector = new \ReflectionClass('Foo');
echo $reflector->getFileName();
```

This will return `false` when the filename cannot be found, e.g. on native classes.

Answer (score 11):

For ReflectionClass in a **namespaced** file, add a prefix "\" to make it global as following:

> $reflector = new \ReflectionClass('FOO');

Or else, it will generate an error said ReflectionClass in a namespace not defined.
*I didn't have rights to make comment for above answer, so I write this as a supplement answer.*

Answer (score 6):

Using a reflector you can build a function like this:

```
function file_by_function( $function_name ){
    if( function_exists( $function_name ) ){
        $reflector = new \ReflectionFunction( $function_name );
    }
    elseif( class_exists( $function_name ) ){
        $reflector = new \ReflectionClass( $function_name );
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
    return $reflector->getFileName();
}
```

file_by_function( 'Foo' ) will return the file path where Foo is defined, both if Foo is a function or a class and false if it's not possible to find the file

Answer (score 0):

if you had an includes folder, you could run a shell script command to "grep" for "class $className" by doing: ``` $filename = ``grep -r "class $className" $includesFolder/*\ ``` and it would return which file it was in. Other than that, i don't think there is any magic function for PHP to do it for ya.

Comment: Honest, non-asshole curiosity here.  What made you think this answer was any better than the idea I'd already considered and rejected?  "
I realize I could use (get_included_files()) to get a list of all the files that have been included so far and then parse them all manually, but that's a lot of file system access for a single attempt."

Comment: because its one line as opposed to however many lines it'd take to write a parser in PHP and the grep function is compiled C, i think, and likely much faster than whatever would have been written.

Comment: Ah, got it.  My actual concern was repeated disk access to each of the files over and over again to do this (it's something that will happen a lot in the tool I'm building) and not the amount of code  I'll try to make that clearer next time. (FYI: You should look into ack.  It's way better than grep!)

Comment: ack or awk? I love awk, its actually my fav programming language, but more people use grep regularly...its "cleaner" for stuff this simple

Comment: Not awk, ack: http://betterthangrep.com/  It's perl back grep replacement that's optimized for search code based projects.  It's great.