# Getting the pathname of an inherited class in PHP

Tags: php, pathname

I'm trying to get the absolute pathname of a PHP class that inherits from a superclass. It seems like it should be simple. I think the code below explains it as succinctly as possible:

```
// myapp/classes/foo/bar/AbstractFoo.php
class AbstractFoo {

    public function getAbsolutePathname() {
        // this always returns the pathname of AbstractFoo.php
        return __FILE__;
    }

}


// myapp/classes/Foo.php
class Foo extends AbstractFoo {

    public function test() {
        // this returns the pathname of AbstractFoo.php, when what I
        // want is the pathname of Foo.php - WITHOUT having to override
        // getAbsolutePathname()
        return $this->getAbsolutePathname();
    }

}
```

The reason I don't want to override `getAbsolutePathname()` is that there are going to be a lot of classes that extend AbstractFoo, in potentially many different places on the filesystem (Foo is actually a module) and it seems like a violation of DRY.

Comment: Aside from the reason why it doesn't work (`__FILE__` is determined at compile time), what is the exact reason you need the filename? IMHO, it's one of the internals one never needs, but I may be overlooking legitimate use.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Finding the PHP File (at run time) where a Class was Defined ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2420066/finding-the-php-file-at-run-time-where-a-class-was-defined)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, you could use [reflection](http://us.php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionobject.php):

```
public function getAbsolutePathname() {
    $reflector = new ReflectionObject($this);
    return $reflector->getFilename();
}
```

I'm not sure if that will return the full path, or just the filename, but I don't see any other relevant methods, so give it a try...

Comment: Thanks @Wrikken...  That's what I get for typing without paying attention to what I'm writing...

Comment: It does in fact return the full path. Perfect!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no clean workaround for this. The magic constants `__FILE__` and `__DIR__` are interpreted during parsing, and are not dynamic.

What I tend to do is

```
class AbstractFoo {

    protected $path = null;

    public function getAbsolutePathname() {

        if ($this->path == null) 
              die ("You forgot to define a path in ".get_class($this)); 

        return $this->path;
    }

}


class Foo extends AbstractFoo {

  protected $path = __DIR__;

}
```

Comment: +1 Replaces `function getAbsolutePathname() { return __DIR__; }` with `private $path = __DIR__;` in each sub-class, which is at least shorter

Comment: Doesn't `$path` need to be `protected` instead of `private`?

Answer (score 0):

You could hack something up with `debug_backtrace`, but that still requires you to explicitly override the parent function in each sub class.

It's far easier to define the function as `return __FILE__;` in each sub class.  `__FILE__` will always be replaced with the file name in which it is found, there is no way to make it do otherwise.