# Finding the PHP File (at run time) where a Method of an Object was Defined

Tags: php, method-declaration

This question is similar to [Finding the PHP File (at run time) where a Class was Defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2420066/finding-the-php-file-at-run-time-where-a-class-was-defined/2420104#2420104)

I can find the file where is defined a Object:

```
$reflector = new ReflectionClass(get_class($object));
echo $reflector->getFileName();
```

But, I need find the method, eg: $object->method() is defined in /var/www/html/object.php line 201

Comment: If no 'real' answers turn up, you could always read the source file using the answer to the linked question, and use a regex to locate the function definition.

Answer (score 1):

My first guess would be to read the php file and find the line where the declaration is using some regex:

```
function getLineWhereMethodIsDefined($object, $method_name) {
    $class_name = get_class($object);
    $reflector = new ReflectionClass($class_name);
    $file_name = $reflector->getFileName();
    foreach (file($file_name) as $i => $line) {
        if (preg_match("'function\s+ " . $method_name . "\('s")) {
            $text = $class_name."::".$method_name."()";
            $text .= " is defined in ".$file_name." on line ".($i + 1);
            return $text;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

This could be improved in memory use, since `file()` reads the whole file into the memory, so with `while(false !== gets()) { }` it would be much more memory effective if you have large files to parse.

**Note:** According to the [ReflectionClass](http://php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionclass.php) documentation, the only information you can get about methods in a class are [ReflectionMethod](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionmethod.php) objects, which do not have information about where the methods are declared. So the above solution looks to be the only way imho.

Comment: 1st, there was no mention about generated code in the question.  
2nd, if the code is generated, eg. not in an actual file, where do you want to get the line number from?

Comment: There are cases for example with the `__call()` magic method, where there is no actual declaration for a method, but the whole thing is about finding actual methods.

Comment: For generate code, File/line where is the eval call + line of eval code

Comment: Well, good luck with that! Btw, I recommend using `debug_backtrace` or throwing some exception in the method, from the trace you can get the information you need.