# preloaded php class file location

Tags: php, class

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Finding the PHP File (at run time) where a Class was Defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2420066/finding-the-php-file-at-run-time-where-a-class-was-defined)

I am working with a server that someone else (currently unavailable) set up.  I am trying to locate the source of a class that apache (or something else) is preloading so that I can update the source code to the correct version of the class.  Running this:

```
<?php echo class_exists('className')? "yes": "no"; ?>
```

(as the entire php file) prints out yes.  How do I find out what file that class is coming from?  I've grepped the server and have a long list of files that it COULD be, but would rather just know which file I need to change without doing a lot of guess and check.  Is there function that will tell me the file with the source code for that class name?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the include path(s) to see which directories are relevant.

get_include_path

http://php.net/manual/de/function.get-include-path.php

Use Reflection class to get the actual file
https://www.php.net/manual/de/reflectionclass.getfilename.php

Comment: thanks, it appears as though the server admin installed it as a PHP extension

Answer (score 3):

```
$r = new ReflectionClass('YourClassName');
echo $r->getFileName();
```

See the documentation page for the reflection class at http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getfilename.php

Per the documentation, classes defined by PHP core (or extension) cause the `getFileName()` method to return `FALSE`.

```
if ($r->getFileName() === FALSE) {echo 'Defined by PHP';}
```