# Find Path/Name of PHP script that contain class definition

Tags: php

I'am looking for a way to find out, witch php script contain a class definition, because i got an error:

`"Cannot redeclare class MyClassName"`

I only have one script in my project, that contain the class definition and require it this way:

```
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/path/to/MyClassName.php');
```

When i use `class_exists('MyClassName')` right befor the require_once, it return true, that means the function has defined.

So now i would like to find out, what script contains the definition.

Is the a function to return a scriptname by given Classname?

Comment: Have you any registered autoloaders? http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-functions.php

Comment: Yes i have some autoloaded classes, for my code, but some of the class files where load with require_once, like the code above (due to the use of an external API deliverer)

Comment: Try and get the filename via a reflector: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2420104/3392762

Comment: Thanks @Progrock the link with the reflector worked for me, found out the hoster aktivate a module that used the same Klassname than my function!