# PHP Fatal error: Cannot redeclare function

Tags: php, apache

I have a function A in file B.inc

```
line 2:  function A() {

           ...

line 10: }
```

In the apache log:

PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare A() (previously declared in B.inc:2) in B on line 10

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I suppose you're using `require "B.inc"` in multiple parts? Can you try using `require_once` in all those instances instead?

Seems like your B.inc is parsed twice.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem where a function entirely contained within a public function within a class was being reported as redeclared. I reduced the problem to

```
class B {
  function __construct() {
   function A() {
   }
  }
 }
 $b1 = new B();
 $b2 = new B();
```

The Fatal error: Cannot redeclare A() is produced when attempting to create $b2.

The original author of the code had protected the class declaration from being redeclared with if ( !class_exists( 'B' ) ) but this does not protect the internal function A() from being redeclared if we attempt to create more than one instance of the class.

Note: This is probably not the same problem as above BUT it's very similar to some of the answers in [PHP Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/708140/php-fatal-error-cannot-redeclare-class)

Comment: This is similar to a problem I had, but my issue was having a named function defined inside a `foreach` loop. The solution ended up being using an anonymous function instead.

Comment: The basic answer for me was: Don't define a function inside a another function.

Answer (score 3):

Did you already declare A() somewhere else?

Or, are you calling B.inc twice on accident?

try using: require_once("B.inc");

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you might be including B.inc more than once.

```
// Rather than
include("B.inc");

// Do:
require_once("B.inc");
```

`require_once()` allows you to call on a file wherever necessary, but only actually parses it if not already parsed.

Answer (score 0):

make sure that you `require_once ( 'B.inc' )` or `include_once ( 'B.inc' )'

Answer (score 0):

These people are all right, but rather use php5, autoload, and instead of functions static methods. Object related methods are mostly better but using static methods enables you to reuse a method name in many classes. 
you can call a static method like this

```
ClassName::myFunction();
```