# Sort Function in 'usort' being "evaled" in PHP? Fatal error: cannot redeclare function?

Tags: php, function, callback, eval, php-5.2

Recently stumbled upon this neat little <strike>bug or</strike> 'feature' in PHP:

```
function myCmpFunc($a,$b) {
    function inner($p) {
         // do something
    }
    $inner_a = inner($a);
    $inner_b = inner($b);
    if ($inner_a == $inner_b) return 0;
    return ($inner_a > $inner_b ? -1 : 1);
}
```

Results in a **fatal error** "cannot redeclare function inner in ...", when called like this

```
usort($myArray, 'myCmpFunc');
```

It works flawlessly when function *inner* is declared outside of *myCmpFunc*
and/or  *$myArray* has not more than 2 elements ;)

-- edit --

somehow Related:
[PHP Fatal error: Cannot redeclare function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5333907/php-fatal-error-cannot-redeclare-function)

So here is my question, then:
Is it possible to declare functions in *local* scope?

-- edit 2 --

Maybe, this works well in PHP 5.3 just read it has closures, yeehaa!

Comment: Writing code that *compiles* but is *invalid* doesn't constitute a PHP *bug*.

Comment: @jason-mccreary you're absolutely right. Nonetheless, I find it useful to declare functions in functions and have them in outer function's local scope. 
Not in PHP, as functions are always in global scope, I learned. Have to use methods, then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`function inner($p)` is defined each time that `function myCmpFunc($a,$b)` is executed. Furthermore, the inner function is visible outside `function myCmpFunc($a,$b)` after that (which pretty much takes the sense out of allowing nested function definitions). That's why you get a duplicate definition error when you call the outer function a second time.

To work around this, check whether [`function_exists`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.function-exists.php) in the body of `function myCmpFunc($a,$b)`.

Answer (score 2):

As of PHP v5.3 one can now write it the nice way:

```
$myCmpFunc = function ($a, $b) {
    static $inner = function ($element) {
         return $element['width']; // just as an example
    };
    $inner_a = $inner($a);
    $inner_b = $inner($b);
    if ($inner_a == $inner_b) return 0;
    return ($inner_a > $inner_b ? -1 : 1);
};
usort($anArray, $myCmpFunc);
```

Answer (score 1):

The function declaration is inside `myCmpFunc`, and because `usort` would call `myCmpFunc` for each element of an array, what happens is similar to declaring a function N times.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is you must call the outer function before using the inner function. As per this answer to a similar question [Can I include a function inside of another function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/708341/can-i-include-a-function-inside-of-another-function-php/4787699#4787699)

So your use of `inner($a);` is not valid.

Comment: @line-o, not within the body of `myCmpFunc`

Comment: This is only true for functions declared inside of conditions.