# Cannot redeclare class Excel error in Codeigniter / PHPExcel

Tags: php, excel, codeigniter, phpexcel

I want to export some data in an Excel file, I got This error.

> A PHP Error was encountered
> Severity: Compile Error
>
> Message: Cannot redeclare class Excel
>
> Filename: libraries/EXcel.php
>
> Line Number: 9

I try some way but no one works in my case. like [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11186348/php-how-to-resolve-cannot-redeclare-class-when-theres-no-previously-declare)  [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/708140/php-fatal-error-cannot-redeclare-class)

This is my `EXcel.php` codes

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

require_once APPPATH."third_party/PHPExcel/PHPExcel.php";
// var_dump(get_declared_classes());
class Excel extends PHPExcel {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
?>
```

what is wrong, thanks.

and this is my Var_dump result:

```
array (size=205)
  0 => string 'stdClass' (length=8)
  1 => string 'Exception' (length=9)
  2 => string 'ErrorException' (length=14)
  3 => string 'Closure' (length=7)
  4 => string 'Generator' (length=9)
  5 => string 'DateTime' (length=8)
  6 => string 'DateTimeImmutable' (length=17)
  7 => string 'DateTimeZone' (length=12)
  8 => string 'DateInterval' (length=12)
  9 => string 'DatePeriod' (length=10)
  10 => string 'LogicException' (length=14)
  11 => string 'BadFunctionCallException' (length=24)
  12 => string 'BadMethodCallException' (length=22)
  13 => string 'DomainException' (length=15)
  14 => string 'InvalidArgumentException' (length=24)
  15 => string 'LengthException' (length=15)
  16 => string 'OutOfRangeException' (length=19)
  17 => string 'RuntimeException' (length=16)
  18 => string 'OutOfBoundsException' (length=20)
  19 => string 'OverflowException' (length=17)
  20 => string 'RangeException' (length=14)
  21 => string 'UnderflowException' (length=18)
  22 => string 'UnexpectedValueException' (length=24)
  23 => string 'RecursiveIteratorIterator' (length=25)
  24 => string 'IteratorIterator' (length=16)
  25 => string 'FilterIterator' (length=14)
  26 => string 'RecursiveFilterIterator' (length=23)
  27 => string 'CallbackFilterIterator' (length=22)
  28 => string 'RecursiveCallbackFilterIterator' (length=31)
  29 => string 'ParentIterator' (length=14)
  30 => string 'LimitIterator' (length=13)
  31 => string 'CachingIterator' (length=15)
  32 => string 'RecursiveCachingIterator' (length=24)
  33 => string 'NoRewindIterator' (length=16)
  34 => string 'AppendIterator' (length=14)
  35 => string 'InfiniteIterator' (length=16)
  36 => string 'RegexIterator' (length=13)
  37 => string 'RecursiveRegexIterator' (length=22)
  38 => string 'EmptyIterator' (length=13)
  39 => string 'RecursiveTreeIterator' (length=21)
  40 => string 'ArrayObject' (length=11)
  41 => string 'ArrayIterator' (length=13)
  42 => string 'RecursiveArrayIterator' (length=22)
  43 => string 'SplFileInfo' (length=11)
  44 => string 'DirectoryIterator' (length=17)
  45 => string 'FilesystemIterator' (length=18)
  46 => string 'RecursiveDirectoryIterator' (length=26)
  47 => string 'GlobIterator' (length=12)
  48 => string 'SplFileObject' (length=13)
  49 => string 'SplTempFileObject' (length=17)
  50 => string 'SplDoublyLinkedList' (length=19)
  51 => string 'SplQueue' (length=8)
  52 => string 'SplStack' (length=8)
  53 => string 'SplHeap' (length=7)
  54 => string 'SplMinHeap' (length=10)
  55 => string 'SplMaxHeap' (length=10)
  56 => string 'SplPriorityQueue' (length=16)
  57 => string 'SplFixedArray' (length=13)
  58 => string 'SplObjectStorage' (length=16)
  59 => string 'MultipleIterator' (length=16)
  60 => string 'ReflectionException' (length=19)
  61 => string 'Reflection' (length=10)
  62 => string 'ReflectionFunctionAbstract' (length=26)
  63 => string 'ReflectionFunction' (length=18)
  64 => string 'ReflectionParameter' (length=19)
  65 => string 'ReflectionMethod' (length=16)
  66 => string 'ReflectionClass' (length=15)
  67 => string 'ReflectionObject' (length=16)
  68 => string 'ReflectionProperty' (length=18)
  69 => string 'ReflectionExtension' (length=19)
  70 => string 'ReflectionZendExtension' (length=23)
  71 => string 'SessionHandler' (length=14)
  72 => string '__PHP_Incomplete_Class' (length=22)
  73 => string 'php_user_filter' (length=15)
  74 => string 'Directory' (length=9)
  75 => string 'ZipArchive' (length=10)
  76 => string 'LibXMLError' (length=11)
  77 => string 'DOMException' (length=12)
  78 => string 'DOMStringList' (length=13)
  79 => string 'DOMNameList' (length=11)
  80 => string 'DOMImplementationList' (length=21)
  81 => string 'DOMImplementationSource' (length=23)
  82 => string 'DOMImplementation' (length=17)
  83 => string 'DOMNode' (length=7)
  84 => string 'DOMNameSpaceNode' (length=16)
  85 => string 'DOMDocumentFragment' (length=19)
  86 => string 'DOMDocument' (length=11)
  87 => string 'DOMNodeList' (length=11)
  88 => string 'DOMNamedNodeMap' (length=15)
  89 => string 'DOMCharacterData' (length=16)
  90 => string 'DOMAttr' (length=7)
  91 => string 'DOMElement' (length=10)
  92 => string 'DOMText' (length=7)
  93 => string 'DOMComment' (length=10)
  94 => string 'DOMTypeinfo' (length=11)
  95 => string 'DOMUserDataHandler' (length=18)
  96 => string 'DOMDomError' (length=11)
  97 => string 'DOMErrorHandler' (length=15)
  98 => string 'DOMLocator' (length=10)
  99 => string 'DOMConfiguration' (length=16)
  100 => string 'DOMCdataSection' (length=15)
  101 => string 'DOMDocumentType' (length=15)
  102 => string 'DOMNotation' (length=11)
  103 => string 'DOMEntity' (length=9)
  104 => string 'DOMEntityReference' (length=18)
  105 => string 'DOMProcessingInstruction' (length=24)
  106 => string 'DOMStringExtend' (length=15)
  107 => string 'DOMXPath' (length=8)
  108 => string 'PDOException' (length=12)
  109 => string 'PDO' (length=3)
  110 => string 'PDOStatement' (length=12)
  111 => string 'PDORow' (length=6)
  112 => string 'SimpleXMLElement' (length=16)
  113 => string 'SimpleXMLIterator' (length=17)
  114 => string 'XMLReader' (length=9)
  115 => string 'XMLWriter' (length=9)
  116 => string 'CURLFile' (length=8)
  117 => string 'COMPersistHelper' (length=16)
  118 => string 'com_exception' (length=13)
  119 => string 'com_safearray_proxy' (length=19)
  120 => string 'variant' (length=7)
  121 => string 'com' (length=3)
  122 => string 'dotnet' (length=6)
  123 => string 'finfo' (length=5)
  124 => string 'GMP' (length=3)
  125 => string 'Collator' (length=8)
  126 => string 'NumberFormatter' (length=15)
  127 => string 'Normalizer' (length=10)
  more elements...
```

Comment: You should look into autoloading instead of manually including the classes you need. Check http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php or use for example Composer's autoloader.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Excel` class is already declared in your project.

Please change your file name and class name of controller to something different. I hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: thanks so much, I have two file by the same name but in the different location of my project I change one of them and it fixes my problem

Comment: @vNasser Ali Karimi Welcome!

Answer (score 1):

source: [Bryan Hazelbaker](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17928529/8740349)

> Depending on your OS, and how you have constructed the path to your document root, there may be an issue with capitals versus lower case letters in the path name.

1. rename the file from `EXcel.php` to `excel.php` (i.e. use lower case)
2. ensure to always use `require_once` (i.e. `require_once /path/to/excel.php`)
3. at last you could test above with `print_r(get_declared_classes());` (which could show you that the first include is from `autoload`)