# Can you reload Boris in Laravel 4.1 without having to exit?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

While using `php artisan tinker`, I changed some class files in my project. Is there a way to reload the REPL without having to type `exit` and `php artisan tinker` again?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If the sequence <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>, <kbd>up</kbd>, <kbd>enter</kbd> is too long for you, you could [file a feature request](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/issues?state=open) with laravel, but last time I checked you couldn't [Redefine Class Methods or Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137006/redefine-class-methods-or-class) , so I think isn't a trivial thing to do.

If tinkering is all you do you could make it even shorter starting your tinker session with

```
$ while true; do php artisan tinker; done
```

Now just the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> will reload the tinker session.

And if that is too much to type you could define a Terminal/iTerm Profile with this command:

```
/bin/sh -c 'while true; do php artisan tinker; done'
```

Comment: Oh yes, 4 key presses are too long! The loop is a good remedy. I was wondering if tinker (or boris) can reset itself. It should be fairly easy to implement.

Comment: @Dave has it become easy to redefine classes and functions in PHP?

Comment: I think resetting the REPL just requires setting a hook in boris and starting a new \Boris\Boris instance.

Comment: `I changed some class files in my project` So then you or Boris will need to re-include them. And last I checked, *that* will result in [I'm sorry @Dave, I'm afraid I can't do that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/708140/php-fatal-error-cannot-redeclare-class). PHP wasn't designed for long running processes, it [evolved](http://php.net/manual/en/history.php.php) from a CGI tool with a runtime with a lifespan of a HTTP request. What your Boris hook needs is a PHP equivalent for Pythons [reload](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reload). If that exists, then it should be easy.

Comment: I was thinking in terms of using PCNTL to do the reset (from TinkerCommand). But now that I think about it, it may not work exactly and if it does, it seems a bit hackish to implement.