# In s2.hacks.php files i having the problems

Tags: php, wordpress

Cannot redeclare geoip_load_shared_mem() (previously declared in /path/to

```
include_once("geo1ip.inc");
```

Comment: See this answer in the duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/a/708150/1450077

Comment: This code is working for me.perfactly...
if(!function_exists('geoip_open')) {
  include_once("geoip.inc");
  }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this in the first few lines of your PHP file:

```
if (!function_exists('geoip_load_shared_mem')) {
    // ... proceed to declare your function
}
```

However if there are multiple functions like this (most likely all the contents from the geo1ip.inc) then you should see why does it see that as already declared (perhaps autoloaders, multiple include of the same files, multiple includes of files containing the same functions)

Comment: I would suggest looking into autoloaders for classes as well. +1