# php - Cannot redeclare class apiException Google+ api

Tags: php, codeigniter, google-plus

**I am getting this error:**

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class apiException in E:\Applications\xampp\htdocs\onlineshop\application\third_party\google-login-api\apiClient.php on line 367

What does it mean?
What should I do to fix it? Add exception in my controller or anything else?
Please help me.

Here's my code

```
public function gplus_login(){
        if(isset($_GET['code'])){
            $this->googleplus->getAuthenticate();
            $user_profile2 = $this->googleplus->getUserInfo();
            $username2 = $user_profile2['email'];
            $password2 = $user_profile2['email'];
            $member_status2 = 1;
            $result2 = $this->m_member->check_login($username2, $password2, $member_status2);
            if($result2 == TRUE){
                $user2 = $this->m_member->by_id(array('member_username'=>$username2));
                $newdata2 = (array(
                        'username_front' => $username2,
                        'member_id'     => $user2->member_id,
                        'member_fullname' => $user2->member_fullname,
                        'logged_in_front' => TRUE
                ));
                $this->session->set_userdata($newdata2);
                redirect('home');
            }
            else{
                $data2 = array(
                        'member_gplus_id'   => $user_profile2["id"],
                        'member_fullname'   => $user_profile2["name"], 
                        'member_email'      => $user_profile2["email"],
                        'member_username'   => $user_profile2["email"],
                        'member_password'   => md5($user_profile2["email"]),
                        'member_status'     => 1,
                        'member_isreseller' => 0,
                        'member_login'      => 0,
                        'created_by'        => $user_profile2["name"],
                        'created_on'        => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
                $this->m_member->insert($data2);
                $user3 = $this->m_member->by_id(array('member_username'=>$username2));
                $newdata3 = (array(
                        'username_front' => $username2,
                        'member_id' => $user3->member_id,
                        'member_fullname' => $user3->member_fullname,
                        'logged_in_front' => TRUE
                    ));
                $this->session->set_userdata($newdata3);
                redirect("account");
            }
         }
        else{
            $this->session->set_flashdata("Login Error");
            redirect("home");
        }

}
```

Comment: There's a lot of possibilities here; please add some of your code to help us help you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/708140/php-fatal-error-cannot-redeclare-class)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think  `apiException` has been included more than 1 time in source code.

Make sure its being used only one time in your source code.

Comment: well i don't use any apiException in my code, how to add or fix it? I Just added my code, tx b4