# php error cannot redeclare class

Tags: php

I have three classes DatabaseHandler, MainPage, and Form

DatabaseHandler.php

```
class DatabaseHandler extends DatabaseConnection
{

}
```

MainPage.php

```
require 'DatabaseHandler.php'
class MainPage
{

}
```

Form.php

```
require 'DatabaseHandler.php'
class Form
{

}
```

on this util.php file it throws an error "cannot redeclare class"

```
//util.php
require 'MainPage.php';
require 'Form.php';
```

how can I avoid this error, i searched before and it says that the only solution is "namespace", i tried reading about it but Im confused and i dont know how to apply it on my situation.

Comment: use `require_once` instead of `require`. This has nothing to do with namespaces. You're just importing `DatabaseHandler.php` twice.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/708140/php-fatal-error-cannot-redeclare-class)

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca that a terrible advice. This should be solved using autoloader, instead of manually wiring the class-files.

Comment: @tereško can you please explain why it's "terrible" (a link would be enough)? I mean, "not the best way to do it" or "not best practice" I wouldn't even ask. But "terrible"?

Comment: For someone just starting out, the advice is good. One step at a time.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca it leads to what one could describe as "include oriented programming".  It basically a way to ruin a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

The `util.php` requires the `MainPage.php` and `Form.php`.

Use `require_once 'DatabaseHandler.php'` instead `of require 'DatabaseHandler.php'`.

This should work!