# Cannot declare class FPDF, because the name is already in use (Wordpress custom plugin)

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I’m new to the forum and I have a problem that is probably super easy to resolve for someone with a little skills in WP developing :-).

I want to create a plugin that creates PDFs. I’m using FPDF since I have been using it before and I think it works great.

My problem is when I try to require the fpdf class I get the error:
Fatal error: Cannot declare class FPDF, because the name is already in use in /wp-content/plugins/tage-test/fpdf181/fpdf.php on line 12

Below is a simplified version where I just try to create a PDF file. If anyone could please help me or point me in the right direction I would really appreciate it!

```
add_shortcode(‘create_invoice’, ‘marathon_form’);
require_once(‘fpdf181/fpdf.php’);

function marathon_form(){
$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->SetDisplayMode(‘fullpage’);
$pdf->SetMargins(0, 15);
$pdf->AddFont(‘VerlagBook’,”,’HBGMv-Book.php’);
$pdf->AddFont(‘VerlagBold’,’B’,’HBGMv-Bold.php’);
$pdf->AddPage(‘P’, ‘A4’);
$pdf->SetFont(‘VerlagBold’,’B’,15);
$pdf->Cell(185,5,’Invoice’,0,1,’R’);

$outputName = ‘invoice.pdf’;
$pdf->Output($outputName, ‘F’);

}
```

Comment: The error message (almost :) ) says it all. I think that you already have another plugin using class FPDF installed. If you delete that plugin (tage-test) it will help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/708140/php-fatal-error-cannot-redeclare-class)

Comment: You are so right Pavel! Thank you so much!